# Product followed by summation

Tags: summation, products

Is it possible to solve this finding the result of the summatory and then, the result of the product?

$\prod_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n} ij$

I already know that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} ij = i\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so I would have to simply find $\prod_{i=1}^{2} i\frac{n(n+1)}{2} $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Adding parentheses for clarity, we have
$$
\prod_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^n ij = \prod_{i=1}^2 \left(\sum_{j=1}^n ij\right).
$$